# Validate Variables in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

Below script is working fine with log getting generated.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_to_check='/root/file_path.txt'
CY=`date +"%Y"`   
TS=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
cmd="/$CY"

cat $dir_to_check | while read output
do
        find ${output}/$cmd -type d -mtime +30 >> /root/file_$TS
        for path in $(cat /root/file_$TS);
                do
        rm -rvf $path | tee -a /root/purge_$TS
        done
done
```

Example locations in `cat /root/file_path.txt` file, all these path have multiple sub directories
from which we need to delete 30 days old data from the directory called `2022` Last years directory and this years directory 2023 respectively.

```
/data/storage/
/hana/storage/
/SAP/storage/
```

Here the issue is from january nothing is deleted from the 2022 folder. need your help in getting it deleted.

Help me validate variable in array, I though of adding array current year & previous year as below by adding below in the above script.

```
PY=`date +%Y -d "-1 years"`
declare -a arr=("$cmd" "$cmd1")
value=21
cmd1="/$PY"


        find ${output}"${arr[@]}" -type d -mtime +30 >> /root/file_$TS
```

Instead getting this as an error.

[image]

So far I have tried this below.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_to_check='/root/file_path.txt'
CY=`date +"%Y"`
PY=`date +%Y -d "-1 years"`
value=21
olddays=`date  --date="21 days ago" +"%Y"`

TS=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
cmd="/$CY"
cmd1="/$PY"

cat $dir_to_check | while read output
do
  if [ $PY == $olddays  ];
then
      find ${output}"$cmd1" -type d -ctime +21 >> /root/file_$TS
    else
      find ${output}"$cmd" -type d -ctime +21 >> /root/file_$TS
  fi
done


for path in $(cat /root/file_$TS);
        do
    rm -rvf $path | tee -a /root/purge_$TS
done
```

Comment: Google: "how to debug bash script" - there are tons of articles on the subject.

Comment: I have debuged it and i know what is the issue, but dont know the logic on how to get this resolved.

Comment: My requirement is to verify if 21 years old date is previous year then select that date as a directory for finding old files for deletion

Comment: Else we can check both directory previous year and current year folders

Comment: Then open another topic with a precise description of what do you want to achieve and show the script you made so far.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Copy and paste the information so it can be easily read

Comment: Your screenshot is unreadable. First step: Put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix it. You also check your code with shellcheck on command line or with VS Code extension